# ASP.NET MVC3 version release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

Currently I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 version with Razor View Engine. Sometimes it is difficult to work with the ".cshtml" files without having intellisense.

Do you have any information as to the release date of original version that supports intellisense?

Comment: Hopefully soon :-) but I don't think there is an official release date yet.... could be wrong....

Comment: Nope - but waiting. In the mean time, I keep this page open at all times : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470179.aspx ;)

Comment: There is syntax highlighter extension available in vs 2010 extension manager for razor

Answer (score 3):

There is no official schedule concerning the release of tooling support for MVC 3 with Razor files.